# Windows 7 tray icons invisible

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

The tray icons are still *there*, but they're just invisible. No amount of clicking will do anything to them.

[image]

Ending and then running `explorer.exe` is a quick fix, but then the icons return to their invisible state upon reboot. I've been dealing with this for a while now and it's starting to get on my nerves.

I have read many articles and tried a bunch of "solutions" such as:

- deleting `iconstreams` and `pasticonstreams` from registry
- installing anti-virus software
- clearing the windows icon cache

but these have not worked.

Any help would be awesome.

**Can you reproduce the issue all the time?**
Yes, every time I reboot my computer they go invisible.

**Are those invisible icons always the same ones?**
Usually they tend to be the same ones, but sometimes Skype is hidden and sometimes it's not, for example.

**Have you run `sfc /scannow` in command prompt as administrator?**

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue all the time? Are those invisible icons always the same ones?

Comment: Have you run "sfc /scannow" in command prompt as an administrator?

Comment: What happens if you *disable hiding tray icons*?  Try going to `Customize...`, force Windows to **not hide any tray icons**, save, restart, and then **switch back** to "Hide Inactive" (or whatever you have it set to now).  This should get rid of any stored force hide/show settings for the tray icons, which happens if you ever manually set a particular icon's force hide/show setting.

Comment: @Breakthrough The icons aren't *hidden*, they're still there, just *invisible* and unusable.

Comment: use tweaking.com's windows all in one repair tool :)

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins that little pop-up window represents any "hidden" tray icons (hidden meaning not immediately visible from the task bar without clicking the little pop-up arrow); in the past, by disabling this feature, then re-enabling it, any invisible/unusable icons that were 'stuck' went away.  I'm not on Windows at the moment, but all you have to do is click `Customize...` and set Windows to Show All Icons or *something* like that (I can't remember the setting name, but when configured, *all* icons should appear on the taskbar - sans the "invisible" ones, now).

Comment: Run SFC with offline option.
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows

Where "c:" is your system drive,what happens while u given it?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins did you try removing suspicious applications from startup, not by an antivirus or anti-malware, but manually with `msconfig.exe`?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins I've seen this on Lenovo laptops that my users have. It always goes away after I uninstall various unnecessary utilities that come from the Lenovo installer. Try uninstalling or disabling Intel Management and Security and Intel RST (those are the only two I recognize) if you don't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following comment by @arielnmz seemed to solve my problem:

```
did you try removing suspicious applications from startup, not by an antivirus
or anti-malware, but manually with msconfig.exe?
```

There wasn't anything out of the ordinary in there, but disabling a bunch of them has solved my problems.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from the article
[How to Reset the Notification Area Icons Cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13102-notification-area-icons-reset.html)
is the file
[Reset_Notification_Area_Icons_Cache.bat](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/246324d1355951211-notification-area-icons-reset-reset_notification_area_icons_cache.bat).

You may download the file, but the contents of the file are also reproduced below :

```
:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13102-notification-area-icons-reset.html

@echo off
cls
set regPath=HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify
set regKey1=IconStreams
set regKey2=PastIconsStream
set choice=Bad-Response

echo The Explorer process must be killed to reset the Notification Area Icons Cache. 
echo.
echo Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing
echo.
pause

echo.
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
echo.
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('Reg Query "%regpath%" /v %regkey1% ^| find /i "%regkey1%"') do goto iconstreams
echo Registry key "IconStreams" already deleted.
echo.

:verify-PastIconsStream
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('Reg Query "%regpath%" /v %regkey2% ^| find /i "%regkey2%"') do goto PastIconsStream
echo Registry key "PastIconsStream" already deleted.
echo.
goto confirm-restart

:iconstreams
reg delete "%regpath%" /f /v "%regkey1%"
goto verify-PastIconsStream

:PastIconsStream
reg delete "%regpath%" /f /v "%regkey2%"

:confirm-restart
echo.
echo.
echo Windows must be restarted to finish resetting the Notification Area Icons. 
echo.

:wrong 
set /p choice=Restart now? (Y/N) and press Enter:
If %choice% == y goto Yes
If %choice% == Y goto Yes
If %choice% == n goto No
If %choice% == N goto No
set choice=Bad-Response
goto wrong

:Yes
shutdown /R /f /t 00
exit

:No
echo.
echo Restart aborted. Please remember to restart the computer later.
echo.
echo You can now close this command prompt window.
explorer.exe
```

Detailed description for running this batch file are included in the article.

Comment: The terms `tray icon` and `notification area icon` are synonymous. If you read through the batch script you see that all it does is delete `iconstreams` and `pasticonstreams` from the registry, which (as stated in my question) I have already tried and did not work.

Comment: Writing for feedback, that this worked to solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to this answer:

> Although this may be overkill, I'd not say that there's some malware
>   that specifically prevents you to do that, but maybe an app that
>   interfers with the expected behaviour:
>
> 1. Run a check using anti-malware tools, like [Adwcleaner](http://www.infospyware.com/antispyware/adwcleaner/) or [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), just in case.
> 2. Open the *msconfig* utility: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and execute `msconfig.exe`.
>
>    - Disable any unwanted applications that run on stratup.
>    - On the *Services* tab, disable any unwanted services that run at startup too. You may want to mark the *Hide Microsoft services* so
>        that you don't disable anything important accidentally.
>    - By default, the `msconfig` utility marks the disabled services as `Disabled`, which means that you can't execute them even manually.
>        Alternatively, you can execute the `services.msc` utility so that you
>        locate such services and change their state to `Manual`, so they don't
>        run on startup automatically but you'd still be able to start them if
>        you need them.
> 3. Reboot and see if something changes, then you can start re-enabling services and apps on startup until you detect which one is
>      causing you trouble.
>
> There are many causes to the behaviour you experiment and these are
>   some steps that may come in handy to detect your issue, but of course
>   it's not the *only* solution.

I have to add that antivirus software isn't that good when it comes to detecting malware, adware and related, that's why you should run a check with dedicated tools like the ones suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is write a script to automatically kill and restart  `explorer.exe` and set it to automatically run when a user logs on.

Script (*.bat):

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM explorer.exe
explorer.exe
```

To get it to automatically run, open the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7), select create task, go to the triggers tab, click new, and select `At log on` from the top drop-down box. Then, go to the actions tab, click new, and enter the path to the script you created (or just click browse and find it). Give the task a name, and you are done!

If you need more clarification, just ask :D

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea that might help, it is simple to try and non invasive. Have you tried updating your video drivers to the most recent version for your machine? I have found in the past this has helped me, maybe it will help you. Let's not forget almost everything in Windows is graphical and drawing the icons certainly uses the video driver, even if it is in a very basic way. I hope this suggestions helps you out.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Download and install **ccleaner**

http://www.filehippo.com/download_cclean...

1. right click on the taskbar and select, task manager.
2. click on the processes tab.
3. now open ccleaner.
4. scroll down to the advanced section of check box's  on the windows tab.
5. check every box in the advanced section but NOT the last two, which
   is wipe free space and custom files and folders.
6. now in the processes in task managerfind explorer.exe  right click
   on it and click on End Process - your taskbar will shut off. (windows explorer will shut down)
7. Now click on Run Cleaner in ccleaner let it clean out all the crap.
8. when it has finished uncheck all the advanced box's and close the
   program.
9. in task manager, click on file (top left), then on New Task (Run...)
10. in the create task box, type in, explorer.exe  then click on OK.
11. if you see a box that says run this task as administrator, make
     sure you check it.

when you have restarted the computer, the job is done.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt processes kill explorer.exe then file new task explorer.exe
Not a permenant solution but it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

in my case wifi was missing and some more tray icons

problem seemed to be wrong webcam driver, video was upside down

I had to download the correct one from asus web page and after reboot it fixed the camera and also missing tray icons.. weird